# Fetch-and-add using OpenMP atomic operations

Tags: c++, atomic, openmp, compare-and-swap

I’m using OpenMP and need to use the fetch-and-add operation. However, OpenMP doesn’t provide an appropriate directive/call. I’d like to preserve maximum portability, hence I don’t want to rely on compiler intrinsics.

Rather, I’m searching for a way to harness OpenMP’s atomic operations to implement this but I’ve hit a dead end. Can this even be done? N.B., the following code *almost* does what I want:

```
#pragma omp atomic
x += a
```

Almost – but not quite, since I really need the old value of `x`. `fetch_and_add` should be defined to produce the same result as the following (only non-locking):

```
template <typename T>
T fetch_and_add(volatile T& value, T increment) {
    T old;
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        old = value;
        value += increment;
    }
    return old;
}
```

(An equivalent question could be asked for compare-and-swap but one can be implemented in terms of the other, if I’m not mistaken.)

Comment: just to say that `atomic` isn't really what its name seems to promise, since any thread which has the memory modified by an `atomic` (on any other thread) cashed will need to re-cache. So frequent and repeated `atomic` may kill your performance (better use locks and buffer racing writes).

Comment: @Walter That’s also what I found empirically: lock-free algorithm performing just on par with the equivalent algorithm using locks. And the lock-free algorithm uses vastly more complex synchronisation – not in terms of performance but in terms of logic (and hence opportunities to introduce bugs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of openmp 3.1 there is support for capturing atomic updates, you can capture either the old value or the new value. Since we have to bring the value in from memory to increment it anyways, it only makes sense that we should be able to access it from say, a CPU register and put it into a thread-private variable.

There's a nice work-around if you're using gcc (or g++), look up atomic builtins:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

It think Intel's C/C++ compiler also has support for this but I haven't tried it.

For now (until openmp 3.1 is implemented), I've used inline wrapper functions in C++ where you can choose which version to use at compile time:

```
template <class T>
inline T my_fetch_add(T *ptr, T val) {
  #ifdef GCC_EXTENSION
  return __sync_fetch_and_add(ptr, val);
  #endif
  #ifdef OPENMP_3_1
  T t;
  #pragma omp atomic capture
  { t = *ptr; *ptr += val; }
  return t;
  #endif
}
```

Update: I just tried Intel's C++ compiler, it currently has support for openmp 3.1 (atomic capture is implemented). Intel offers free use of its compilers in linux for non-commercial purposes:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/non-commercial-software-download/

GCC 4.7 will support openmp 3.1, when it eventually is released... hopefully soon :)

Comment: I’ve resorted to using GCC builtins anyway but of course this is horrible for interoperability. Thanks for the OpenMP 3.1 pointer. Unfortunately, since VC++ currently doesn’t even support OpenMP 3, this is rather theoretical for the moment.

Comment: Just for completenes: it should be `#ifdef __GNUC__` ... `#elif defined(_OPENMP) and _OPENMP>=201107` (for OpenMP 3.1) ... `#else #error "Requires gcc or OpenMP>=3.1" #endif`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get old value of x and a is not changed, use (x-a) as old value:

```
fetch_and_add(int *x, int a) {
 #pragma omp atomic
 *x += a;

 return (*x-a);
}
```

UPDATE: it was not really an answer, because x can be modified after atomic by another thread.
So it's seems to be impossible to make universal "Fetch-and-add" using OMP Pragmas. As universal I mean operation, which can be easily used from any place of OMP code.

You can use `omp_*_lock` functions to simulate an atomics:

typedef struct { omp_lock_t lock; int value;} atomic_simulated_t;

```
fetch_and_add(atomic_simulated_t *x, int a)
{
  int ret;
  omp_set_lock(x->lock);
  x->value +=a;
  ret = x->value;
  omp_unset_lock(x->lock);
}
```

This is ugly and slow (doing a 2 atomic ops instead of 1). But If you want your code to be very portable, it will be not the fastest in all cases.

You say "as the following (only non-locking)". But what is the difference between "non-locking" operations (using CPU's "LOCK" prefix, or LL/SC or etc) and locking operations (which are implemented itself with several atomic instructions, busy loop for short wait of unlock and OS sleeping for long waits)?

Comment: And for cas - openmp supports a variant of conditional atomic, but only in fortran. It is a MIN and MAX; they are conditional. Can be used to implement a subset of CAS operations.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, I too, because it takes me 1 week to get this :). Also, the required step for me was a learning LL/SC operation on different platforms.

Comment: @osgx: this isn’t actually a problem since you can simply coerce the types to an integer of the appropriate bit size beforehand. Granted, that’s UB and platform-dependent but with the appropriate guards in place this is a very reliable technique.

Comment: Damn, this answer isn’t correct either: between the atomic update and the last line another thread might of course modify `x`!

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, yes, first try was wrong. Updated an answer.