# std::vector push_back fails when used in a parallel for loop

Tags: c++, vector, parallel-processing, thread-safety, openmp

I have a code that is as follow (simplified code):

```
for( int i = 0; i < input.rows; i++ )
{
    if(IsGoodMatch(input[I])
    { 
        Newvalues newValues;
        newValues.x1=input.x1;
        newValues.x2=input.x1*2;
        output.push_back( newValues);
    }
}
```

This code works well, but if I want to make it parallel using omp parallel for, I am getting error on output.push_back and it seems that during vector resize, the memory corrupted.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

How can I make sure only one thread inserting a new item into vector at any time?

Comment: Are you using any synchronization mechanisms?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: no! The code is as shown above!

Comment: Non-const functions of `std` containers are not thread-safe; you must synchronise if you want to modify them concurrently.

Comment: You're lucky that you didn't call `output.reserve(input.rows)`. That would have prevented the memory reallocation, but the code would still be thread-unsafe. And that might manifest itself in "missing" values, which would be far harder to spot.

Comment: Must the output be ordered like the input? Keeping that order is a bit of a challenge when the actual input isn't processed in-order, and there's no 1 to 1 match with `output[]`. Depending on the relative speeds of all functions, it may be worthwhile to determine `goodInput[]` sequentially, and then convert that 1 to 1, in parallel, to `output[]`. If `isGoodMatch` is the problem, calculate `inputMask[]` in parallel, and then do the remainder sequentially.

Comment: @MSalters: output doesn't need to be in the same order as input.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think, "I know, I'll use threads," and then two they hav erpoblesms.

Answer (score 8):

The simple answer is that `std::vector::push_back` is not thread-safe.

In order to safely do this in parallel you need to synchronize in order to ensure that `push_back` isn't called from multiple threads at the same time.

Synchronization in C++11 can easily be achieved by using an `std::mutex`.

Comment: Why not just put a `#pragma omp critical` before the push_back?

Comment: @DavidDoria I am not familiar with OpenMP and simply gave the standard C++ solution.

Comment: @DavidDoria your suggestion worked perfectly for me.  You should make it an official answer

Comment: @VinceW. I just posted the 'critical' recommendation as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

`std::vector`'s `push_back` can not guarantee a correct behavior when being called in a concurrent manner like you are doing now (there is no thread-safety).

However since the elements don't depend on each other, it would be very reasonable to `resize` the vector and modify elements inside the loop separately:

```
output.resize(input.rows);
int k = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for shared(k, input)
for( int i = 0; i < input.rows; i++ )
{
    if(IsGoodMatch(input[I])
    { 
        Newvalues newValues;
        ...
        // ! prevent other threads to modify k !
        output[k] = newValues;
        k++;
        // ! allow other threads to modify k again !
    }
} 

output.resize(k);
```

since the direct access using `operator[]` doesn't depend on other members of `std::vector` which might cause inconsistencies between the threads. **However** this solution might still need an explicit synchronization (i.e. using a synchronization mechanism such as mutex) that will ensure that a correct value of `k` will be used.

*"How can I make sure only one thread inserting a new item into vector at any time?"*

You don't need to. Threads will be modifying different elements (that reside in different parts of memory). You just need to make sure that the element each thread tries to modify is the correct one.

Comment: This doesn't work as the number of items in output is not the same as input. Please look at if(isGoodmatch())

Comment: @mans: See my edit. Still you can rely on `output.size()` <= `input.size()`

Comment: You still need to make `output[k] = newValues; k++;` atomic, or there is a race condition, as two threads can both write to the same `k`.

Comment: @AntonGuryanov: Although this sounds perfectly reasonable, I think incrementing an `int` variable this way should be handled by OMP (but I must admit that I'm  not sure though)

Comment: @LihO: even if `k++` is atomic, it doesn't follow that if `output[k] = newValues` is threadsafe and `k++` is atomic, then `output[k] = newValues; k++;` is atomic. Two threads could both see the same value of `k` in the fist line before either one of them increments it in the second line.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, I understand Anton's point, but... Are you sure this isn't handled internally by OMP?

Comment: @LihO: I'm not *certain* that it isn't, I've never used OMP. But it seems like quite a big claim to me, that I'd consider unlikely unless someone is sure it is. Do you mean that OMP will detect all uses of `k` in the loop, and make the block of code from the first to the last into an atomic operation? For a slightly different loop (one that uses `k` early in the loop body) that could prevent OMP from doing any parallelization at all. But maybe that's the point of declaring `k` shared, I don't know...

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, that's what I was pointing out... that there might be more complex functionality hidden behind it when we explicitly express that `k` is shared between the threads. However I've edited my answer :)

Comment: [The correct way to capture and increment k](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7918281/15416)

Comment: @MSalters: That is an awesome link :)

Answer (score 2):

Use concurrent vector

```
#include <concurrent_vector.h>
```

`Concurrency::concurrent_vector<int>` in c++11.

It is thread safe version of vector.

Comment: I don't see _any_ evidence anywhere that `concurrent_vector` is "in c++11". There's an implementation of it in Intel's Threading Building Blocks as [`tbb:concurrent_vector`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506203), and Microsoft's Concurrency Runtime (ConCRT) has a a [`concurrency::concurrent_vector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/reference/concurrency-namespace?view=vs-2019), but those are specific to Intel TBB and Visual C++, respectively. (OpenMP _can_ be used in MSVC, granted. But Intel recommends not mixing it with TBB.)

Answer (score 2):

Put a `#pragma omp critical` before the `push_back`.

Answer (score -9):

You can try to use  a mutex to fix the problem.
Usually I prefer to achieve such thing myself;

```
static int mutex=1;
int signal(int &x)
{
    x+=1;
    return 0;
}
int wait(int &x)
{
    x-=1;
    while(x<0);
    return 0;
}
for( int i = 0; i < input.rows; i++ )
{
    if(IsGoodMatch(input[I])
    {
        Newvalues newValues;
        newValues.x1=input.x1;
        newValues.x2=input.x1*2;
        wait(mutex);
        output.push_back( newValues);
        signal(mutex);
    }
}
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: Good demonstration of why you shouldn't try to write your own mutex

Comment: Using a mutex to synchronize accesses to the vector is a plausible approach, but the only thing your code synchronizes it the CPU temperature with the time your program is executed.